# React native image annotations containing a link to a site

Tags: react-native, image-annotations

I am a complete beginner at react-native. I am trying to create an app where i can take multiple photos and add a tag/label with a link to a website to each of the photos. These links when tapped need to take the user to the specified website. I also want to be able to save all of the tags along with the images for later in the app. I have found some resources(components) regarding this but as a beginner, i do not know how to use any of them. I am listing these below. If anyone can help to use these or give me any direction as to how i can make this project, i would be really grateful.

resources i found:

1. https://github.com/skicson/react-native-image-annotation
2. https://github.com/JimmyDaddy/react-native-image-marker